# How to jump back to the previous line in Vim

Tags: vim

I am new to `Vim`, my code file has 300 lines, and suppose currently the cursor is on line 254, and when use `gg` command the cursor turn to line 1, and I want to back to line 254 but I forget that line number. Is there a command the can do this? 
And when I want to jump a line, I input `:38`, and I want to jump back to the previous line, what should I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> jumps backward to the previous location.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> jumps forward to the next location.

`:jumps` or `:ju` gives you a jump list.

Use `jump number` followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to jump to that particular location.

Ex: <kbd>20</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
``
```

(backtick, backtick)

This sends you back to the place you last jumped from. To learn more about this, type `:help ''`. That whole help document is worth reading.

Comment: if I input `:78` to line 78, and I want to jump to previous line, the `\`\`` seems just jump to line 1. What should I do?

Comment: @Alexander, could you clarify what do you mean by 'previous line'? Line 77? You can get there with `k`.

Comment: This not line 77, for example the current line is `290` and I input `:77`, and now it jumps to line `77` and the previous line is `290`.

Comment: @Alexander: Just try Ctrl-O and Ctrl-I for a couple of times, you will understand.